# Integral Metric on $C([0,1])$

Tags: convergence-divergence, metric-spaces, uniform-convergence, cauchy-sequences

Please  consider the example below:[image][image]

> Although I understand much of the solution, I do not understand why $f_n(t) = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt t}~\forall~n \ge p$. Could someone help me with understanding this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just by definition of $f_n$. It is defined for $t\in\big[\frac{1}{n^2},1\big]$ as
$$
f_n(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}.\tag{1}
$$
If $n\ge p$ then $\big[\frac{1}{p^2},1\big]\subset\big[\frac{1}{n^2},1\big]$, hence, (1) holds for $n\ge p$ **and** $t\in\big[\frac{1}{p^2},1\big]$.